Libexpat Vulnerabilities exists in python:3.11-slim Docker Image
There are three vulnerabilities: CVE-2024-45490, CVE-2024-45491 and CVE-2024-45492).
It looks, these vulnerabilities get fixed as part of https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/123678
But when I pull the latest python:3.11-slim image
docker pull python:3.11-slim
3.11-slim: Pulling from library/python
Digest: sha256:669bbd08353610485a94d5d0c976b4b6498c55280fe42c00f7581f85ee9f3121

It still shows vulnerabilities.
Any suggestion would be recommended.
I am using the latest SHA version, (Both from AWS ECR and dockerhub). though both has same SHA
docker pull public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.11-slim
3.11-slim: Pulling from docker/library/python
92c3b3500be6: Already exists 
89790d4ca55c: Already exists 
01ac286af1cc: Already exists 
4ba8b3df285e: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:669bbd08353610485a94d5d0c976b4b6498c55280fe42c00f7581f85ee9f3121

docker pull python:3.11-slim
3.11-slim: Pulling from library/python
Digest: sha256:669bbd08353610485a94d5d0c976b4b6498c55280fe42c00f7581f85ee9f3121


While this has been fixed in cpython and released with 3.11.10, the package seems to be installed via apt in the Docker image (check layer 7) which is where the vulnerability comes from. It seems like the updated package wasn't in the Debian package registry when the image was created.

Also you might want to check whether you are actually affected.

Thanks @dan1st. That makes sense. Yes, expat package get installed via apt in the Docker Image, https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/9cd324371ef929bfc5036a00d7705a213d8b5020/3.11/slim-bookworm/Dockerfile#L42C3-L42C16
But Looks it's installing 2.5.0-1 version of expat, instead of latest one 2.6.3
https://packages.debian.org/sid/expat (Though 2.6.3 I could see here)
But when I manually run
apt-get upgrade libexpat1, Looks it still installed 2.5.0-1+deb12u1 which has 3C Vulnerbailities.

@SumanshuNankana did you get this resolved?  What was your approach?  thx!

No, It did not resolved.

Moving to python:3.11.10-slim-bookworm solved this for me. I would bet that just moving to 3.11.10 would have done it as well.
